# jQuery Supersized - Insert Caption into Slideshow Items

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, supersized

I'm using [jQuery supersized](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/) and am looking to insert the slide_caption into each slideshow item, so the captions "slide" with each image, rather than just hanging out somewhere on the page.

I've got this going fairly well by adding this into my supersized theme's init function:

```
if ($(vars.slide_caption).length){$('#supersized li').append($('.projectcaption'));}
```

And then I added this to the beforeAnimation function:

```
beforeAnimation : function(direction){ 
        // Update slide caption
        if ($(vars.slide_caption).length){
            (api.getField('title')) ? $(vars.slide_caption).html(api.getField('title')) : $(vars.slide_caption).html('');
        }    
    }
```

The issue is that the current slide's caption changes to the next slide's title, instead of only replacing the up-coming title. This is probably because I'm using a class (.projectcaption) as my slide title and there's more than one on the page, but it's gotta be a class and not an ID.

http://future.thefutureforward.com/~merrell/project-test.html

Any ideas as to how to get the slide title to slide out with each slide, but not alter the existing slide's title as well would be amazing!

Answer (score 0):

**So this isn't working with more than three images...any thoughts out there on how to edit?**

--

What I ended up doing was wrapping the call to the beforeAnimation function in the primary supersized plugin file using "setTimeout". I then added a delay as necessary and tweaked it until the text switched out at just the right time:

```
if(typeof theme != 'undefined' && typeof theme.beforeAnimation == "function")setTimeout(function(){theme.beforeAnimation('next')},80);
```

Remember that it's called three times in that file (once for initial load, once for when clicking "next", and once for clicking "previous"). It's a bit of a hack and takes some adjusting of the millisecond delay depending on the speed of your slide, but it functions well.

http://future.thefutureforward.com/~merrell/project-test.html